# Is there a close approximation for $\prod_{i=1}^n (1-1/p_i)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

Consider the primes $p_i$ starting at $p_1 = 2$.  Is there a close approximation for

$$\prod_{i=1}^n (1-1/p_i)\;?$$

Plotting the values you get the following.

[image]

Comment: What is your background in Number Theory? What did you attempted?

Comment: @3ibfwcbi I have only written code to compute values. My number theory is really at basic undergraduate level.

Comment: Here is a nice article about the Riemannian $\zeta$ function, which is what we get if we multiply over all (infinitely many) primes. https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/the-extended-riemann-hypothesis-and-ramanujans-sum/#toggle-id-1-closed

Comment: If you see an answer you like, the site approved thing to do is to hit the little check mark below the voting part of the question. It lets others know the question has been answered, and it shoots a little dopamine in my brain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've discovered Merten's 3rd theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems)!

This states, in your notation, that

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(p_n)}.$$

Here, $"\sim"$ means that the two ratio between these two quantities approaches $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity, $e$ is Euler's constant, and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. There are stronger error bounds, assuming stronger versions of the Prime Number Theorem.

If you don't know the Prime Number Theorem, it states that $p_n\sim n\ln(n)$. By "stronger versions", I mean some version of this theorem where we bound the error between $p_n$ and $n\ln(n)$. Using this theorem, we can restate Merten's theorem as

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(n\ln(n))}=\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))}.$$

However, since $\ln(\ln(n))$ is small relative to $\ln(n)$ this can equivilantly be seen as

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(n)}.$$

Comment: Do you know a reference for the added $\ln(\ln(n))$ term in the denominator?

Comment: @graffe I'm not sure what you're asking. The $\ln(\ln(n))$ term from using the fact that $\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$

Comment: I need to study the derivation Mertens theorem I think. I did some numerical computation and it is very accurate already for $n > 10^6$.

Answer (score -3):

Let us consider
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=1}^\infty \left(1-\dfrac{1}{p_i}\right)&=\left(\prod_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{p_i }{p_i-1}\right)^{-1}=\left(\prod_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{1-p_i^{-1}}\right)^{-1}=\zeta(1)^{-1}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n} \right)^{-1}
\end{align*}
This series diverges, i.e. tends to infinity, so its inverse tends to zero. Your question can therefore be rephrased as to how fast the harmonic series increases. One possible answer to that is
$$
\int_1^{n+1}\dfrac{dx}{x}<\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{i}<1+\int_1^{n}\dfrac{dx}{x}
$$