# How accurate is $\prod_{p < y} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$ for the number of $y$-rough integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Call a positive integer $y$-rough if it has no factors below $y$.  I am interested in accurate ways to estimate the number of positive integers less than or equal to $x$ that are $y$-rough. Assuming that $x > y^2$, one option is first to compute:

$$P=\prod_{p < y} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$$

where the $p$ are primes.

We can then give $xP$ as the estimate.

What can be said about how accurate this estimate is?

Comment: I am only aware of asymptotic results. The estimate should be quite accurate if $x$ is much larger than $y$ (say $\ln(x)>3\ln(y)$ holds). Note that $P$ is asymptotically $$\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(y)}$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: @Peter I would really like a non-asymptotic result.  Where does $\ln(x) > 3\ln(y)$ come from and can "quite accurate" be quantified?

Comment: I wondered this a long time ago as well and I only found the Buchstab function, but nowhere a good estimate of the error we make.

Comment: @Peter I may end up posting on MO but I will leave it a few days here first.

Comment: "$\ln(x)>3\ln(y)$" is an ad-hoc and intuitive thumb rule. I think if this holds , the dependecies of the residues modulo the primes can be considered to be small enough.

Comment: Remember that you should not crosspost. If you post it on MO, then delete it here. Also, perhaps a link to your [former question(s)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4600283/is-there-a-close-approximation-for-prod-i-1n-1-1-p-i) might be helpful for context.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is another site. What speaks against posting it there as well ? Or is it just a rule ?

Comment: @Peter It is not me speaking against something. See [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) and other places, where it is recommended not to crosspost: "Ask the question on the site you think is most applicable. Each site is focused on a specific topic area and it's important to respect the community."

Comment: You shouldn't delete the question here, since that deletes the work of people who have tried to help you. But you shouldn't crosspost until several days have gone by without a useful answer here, and if you do crosspost you should link each post to the other, and you should explain on the other site what is inadequate about the answers/comments you have received here.

Comment: Buchstab function is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchstab_function and perhaps the links there will get you started.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am not sure of the exact relationship of Buchstab’s function to my question. In particular where w(u) would appear for the estimate I describe.

Comment: @GerryMyerson also I am interested in specific numerical errors bounds given specific values of x and y.

Comment: I know that. My link is a place to start your explorations, not the place to finish them.

Comment: Any comments on the answers you have received?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have learned that my question isn't easy to answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how much analytic number theory you know, so if this is way past your pay grade then let me know and perhaps there's an elementary method I can find. This is just the general method that almost always works with this sort of problem.

Suppose we want to count the amount of $y$-rough numbers. Let $i_n$ be the indicator function for $y$-rough numbers, i.e,

$$i_n=
\begin{cases}
1 & n \text{ is }y\text{-rough}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

We construct the Dirichlet series

$$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{i_n}{n^s}.$$

It is clear that $nm$ is $y$-rough if and only if both $n$ and $m$ are $y$-rough, and hence $i_{nm}=i_{n}i_{m}$. Thus, we have an Euler product expansion

\begin{align*}
f(s)&=\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{i_p}{p^s}+\frac{i_{p^2}}{p^{2s}}...\right)\\
&=\prod_{p\geq y}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}+\frac{1}{p^{2s}}...\right)\\
&=\prod_{p\geq y}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}\\
&=\zeta(s)\prod_{p<y}(1-p^{-s}).
\end{align*}

In particular, since $\lim_{s\to 1}(s-1)\zeta(s)=1$, we have

$$\lim_{s\to 1}(s-1)f(s)=\prod_{p<y}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right).$$

The [Hardy-Littlewood Tauberian Theore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_Tauberian_theorem) gives us thus that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n<x}i_{n}=\prod_{p<y}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right).$$

This is exactly the statement that your approximation is correct, i.e, the proportion of $y$-rough numbers tends to $\prod_{p<y}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$. To get uniform error bounds, you could use stronger analytic number theory results. For instance, [Perron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula) says that

$$\sum_{n<x}i_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz$$

for any $c>1$. Now, $f(s)$ has no poles apart from the one at $s=1$ and hence using Cauchy's integral formula we can push $c$ as close as we want to 0. Hence, we get that

$$\left(\text{proportion of }y\text{-rough numbers less than }x \right)=\prod_{p<y}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)+O(1/(x^{1-\epsilon}))$$

for every $\epsilon>0$. The constant in the big-Oh depends on $\epsilon$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you for this! You switched to y-smooth at the end. Did you mean to?

Comment: I think your references are missing too.

Comment: @Simd Oops, that was a mistake. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Simd Oh, yes. This was copy pasted from yesterday's version of your question, and the references didn't carry through: It's fixed now.

Comment: If we fix x and y can this method give an error bound? Say $x=2^{20}$ and $y=2^9$.

Comment: I'm sure you could. The key estimate would be upper bounding $f(s)$ with respect to $y$ on $\Re(s)=0$. This would then make the constant from Perron's formula explicit. I'd recommend you do this as an exercise!

Comment: I am not sure I know though to do this but I will try. I might end up asking a separate question about it.

Answer (score 2):

Carl Pomerance gave a talk, "The sieve of Eratosthenes and rough numbers," at the recent Number Theory meeting in Monterey. He lets $\Phi(x,y)$ be the number of integers $n\le x$ with no prime factors $\le y$. His graduate student, Steve Fan, proved
$$
\Phi(x,y)\le{x\over\log y},\quad x\ge y\ge2
$$
Fan and Pomerance together proved, for $3\le y\le\sqrt x$, we have
$$
\Phi(x,y)<0.6x/\log y
$$
I don't know whether these results are published yet, but Carl is good at posting his work to his website, you could have a look there.

Comment: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/rough.pdf

Comment: I read their paper but sadly they say numerical bounds will come in a later paper.  I also implemented their expanded version of Buchstab's function but it is almost identical numerically to the non-expanded version and still approx 3% off for simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the question now has a bounty, so I guess my previous answer wasn't satisfactory. I'll make the upper bound explicit. Fix $T\geq 1$, and $1/2\geq\delta>0$. Explicit versions of Perron's formula tell us that

\begin{equation}
\left| \sum_{n<x}i_n\right|=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{2-iT}^{2+iT}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz\right|+O\left(\frac{x\log(x)}{T}\right).
\end{equation}

The constant in the $O$ is uniform with respect to everything, i.e, an error bound of $10x\log(x)/T$ might hold. I have a gripe with people who treat Perron's formula with rarely making constants of this sort explicit. If I could find a reference with a number instead of a $O$ that would be great.

Now, we have by Cauchy's integral formula that

$$\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{2-iT}^{2+iT}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz\right|=x\prod_{p<y}(1-1/p)+\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta-iT}^{\delta+iT}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz\right|+2\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta+iT}^{2+iT}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z} \right|.$$

To bound these, we need upper bounds on $f(z)$. It is well known (see for example page 97 of [these](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Epubl/ln/tifr01.pdf) notes) that for $\sigma\geq\delta$, and $t \geq 1$, there is an upper bound

$$|\zeta(\sigma+it)|\leq \left(\frac{1}{1-\delta}+1+\frac{3}{\delta}\right)t^{1-\delta}.$$

Additionally, we have that

$$\left|\prod_{p<y}\left(1-p^{-s}\right)\right|\leq \prod_{p<y}\left(1+p^{-\Re(s)}\right)\leq 2^{\pi(y)}.$$

Thus,

$$f(\delta+it)\leq 2^{\pi(y)}\left(\frac{1}{1-\delta}+1+\frac{3}{\delta}\right)t^{1-\delta}\leq 2^{\pi(y)+3} \cdot \delta^{-1} \cdot t^{1-\delta}.$$

Hence,

$$\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta+iT}^{2+iT}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z} \right|\leq 2^{\pi(y)+2}\cdot \delta^{-1}\cdot T^{-\delta}\cdot x^{\delta}.$$

Collecting, we get that

\begin{equation}
\left| \sum_{n<x}i_n\right|=x\prod_{p<y}(1-1/p)+\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta-iT}^{\delta+iT}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz\right|+O\left(\frac{x\log(x)}{T}+2^{\pi(y)}\cdot \delta^{-1}\cdot T^{-\delta}\cdot x^{\delta}\right).
\end{equation}

Splitting up the integral one last time, we have

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta-iT}^{\delta+iT}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz\right|&\leq 2\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta+i}^{\delta+iT}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz\right|+\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta-i}^{\delta+i}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz\right|. \\
\end{align*}

For the first integral, we use the previous bounds:

\begin{align*}
2\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta+i}^{\delta+iT}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz\right|&\leq O\left(\int_{1}^{T}\frac{x^{\delta}\cdot 2^{\pi(y)}\cdot \delta^{-1}}{t^{\delta}}\right)\\
&\leq O\left(x^{\delta}\cdot 2^{\pi(y)}\cdot \delta^{-1}\cdot T^{1-\delta}\right).\\
\end{align*}

For the second, we use that $\zeta(z)$ is bounded in a fixed neighborhood of $0$. Hence, we get that

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta-i}^{\delta+i}f(z)\frac{x^z}{z}dz\right|
&=O\left(2^{\pi(y)}\cdot x^{\delta}\cdot \delta^{-1}\right)
\end{align*}

We thus have the big integral-free estimate

\begin{align*}
\left| \sum_{n<x}i_n\right|&=x\prod_{p<y}(1-1/p)+2^{\pi(y)}\cdot\delta^{-1}\cdot O\left(x^{\delta}\cdot T^{1-\delta}+\frac{x\log(x)}{T}\right).
\end{align*}

The trick is now to find the correct value of $T$. If the estimate had been done better, a good choice of $\delta$ would have given an approximation of the form $x^{\delta}\log(x)$. Seeing as it was done poorly, we can only get down to about $x^{1/2}$. For the sake of concreteness we fix $\delta$ away from $0$, and get the estimate

\begin{align*}
\left| \sum_{n<x}i_n\right|&=x\prod_{p<y}(1-1/p)+O\left(2^{\pi(y)}\cdot x^{3/4}\right).
\end{align*}

Even if we got down to $x^{\epsilon}$ for small $\epsilon$, this wouldn't work out. Namely, $x>y^2$ is not enough using this method. The error is almost exponential in $y$ but polynomial in $x$. If you wanted to try to get improvements, you would need to find a way to bound

$$\prod_{p<y}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^z}\right)$$

as $z$ ranges over the complex plane, and the real part of $z$ approaches $0$. In particular, you need to prove that not all of the $1/p^z$ can approximate $-1$ simultaneously.

Comment: How small does y have to be for this method?

Comment: y<log(x), more or less

Comment: Ah ok. I am sorry my question just turns out to have been much harder than I expected.